How can I prove the injectivity of plus?
Here's what I'm trying to prove: Theorem add_n_injective : forall n m p, n + m = n + p -> m = p.
I've tried Coq's built-in tactices, but they don't work. Is there an easy way to prove this?
Here's what I've done:
Theorem plus_injective : forall n m, n + n = m + m -> n = m.
Proof. intros n m H.
       induction n.
       - simpl in H. induction m.
         + reflexivity.
         + rewrite H. discriminate.
       - simpl in H. induction m.
         + simpl in H. rewrite <- H. discriminate.
         + rewrite <- H in IHn. rewrite IHn in IHm.
            
Qed.

and its got stuck with one subgoal

2n = 2m -> n = m is not the injectivity of plus but that of twice !

You need to show (S n) + (S n) = S (S (n+n))  to proceed by induction as you want. In turn, this means you need n+S m = S (n+m) which is part of the StdLib used to show that + is eg commutative.

You can not use your induction hypothesis because H simplifies to n + n = m + m while IHn expects n + n = S m + S m. In other words, the argument m you want to feed the induction hypothesis changed, which is a symptom that you need to generalize over m (with revert m) before doing induction n (actually you can just not introduce m and H before doing induction n). Besides, you can also destruct m instead of doing an induction on it, the induction hypothesis IHm is useless.

How would you prove it on paper? I'd say probably not by induction. Maybe you already have the inverse of +n?
Note that there is also the lia tactic for solving linear integer arithmetic problems. You just need to import it with the following command.
From Coq Require Import Lia.

